Unable to send value in Autosearch Field using selenium C#


<div class="mat-mdc-form-field-infix ng-tns-c2608167813-93">
  <!----><input _ngcontent-ng-c274796792="" type="text" matinput="" autocomplete="off" class="mat-mdc-input-element mat-mdc-autocomplete-trigger ng-tns-c2608167813-93 ng-valid mat-mdc-form-field-input-control mdc-text-field__input cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-dirty ng-touched"
    id="mat-input-58" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-controls="mat-autocomplete-1">
  <!---->
  <mat-autocomplete _ngcontent-ng-c274796792="" class="mat-mdc-autocomplete ng-tns-c1630904807-94 ng-tns-c2608167813-93 ng-star-inserted">
    <!---->
  </mat-autocomplete>
</div>





<div class="mat-mdc-form-field-infix ng-tns-c2608167813-21">
  <!----><input _ngcontent-ng-c274796792="" type="text" matinput="" autocomplete="off" class="mat-mdc-input-element mat-mdc-autocomplete-trigger ng-tns-c2608167813-21 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid mat-mdc-form-field-input-control mdc-text-field__input cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored"
    id="mat-input-6" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox">
  <!---->
  <mat-autocomplete _ngcontent-ng-c274796792="" class="mat-mdc-autocomplete ng-tns-c1630904807-22 ng-tns-c2608167813-21 ng-star-inserted">
    <!---->
  </mat-autocomplete>
</div>



I have form on Angular web application which I want fill and submit. There is one field in the form which is autosearch field. I Tried sending value in this field using SendKeys ,Actions Class & JavaScript but nothing is working until I physically type any letter on the field.
below are the different method I used to automate this field:-
// 1.
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(LocatorofElement).SendKeys("Value");

// 2. 
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("arguments[0].value = 'Value'; ", LocatorofElement);

// 3. 
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("var event=new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{key:'a'});arguments[0].dispatchEvent(event);", LocatorofElement);

// 4. 
LocatorofElement.SendKeys("Value");


Please provide a link to the page. Without it we are unlikely to be able to help you.

Application is internal application of my company. I can share HTML of the Field.

Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted.

It seems like the autosearch field on the Angular web application may have some specific event triggering or validation that is not being met when you try to send values using Selenium. One possible solution could be to try triggering the key events like keydown, keyup, and keypress events along with sending the value.
You can try the following code snippet to send a value to the autosearch field:
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LocatorofElement);
element.Click();
element.SendKeys("Value");
element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

By clicking on the element before sending the keys, it may trigger the necessary events for the autosearch field to work properly. Additionally, sending the Enter key after sending the value may help in submitting the value in the autosearch field.
Give this a try and see if it helps in sending values to the autosearch field using Selenium in C#.

Thanks for the Response, but this is not working. Can you help me how can I trigger Key press event., since Sendkeys is not working.
